Showcasing deepDiff results in json content as highlights using Angular?
I am using deepDiff to show the differences between two jsons in a structural manner, so far so good. But I want to highlight the differences, within the parsed jsons contents. It is not really working.How could I solve this?
function for getting the differences:
 compareFiles() {
    if (this.file1Content && this.file2Content) {
      const differences = deepDiff.diff(this.file1Content.apis, this.file2Content.apis);

      if (differences) {
        this.comparisonResult = this.formatDifferences(differences);
        const filteredDifferences = differences.filter(diff => diff.path && !diff.path.some(p => p.key === 'index' && p.ignoreOrder));
        this.comparisonResult2 = filteredDifferences ? JSON.stringify(filteredDifferences, null, 2) : 'No differences found.';

        this.highlightedFile1Content = this.getHighlights(this.file1Content, differences);
        this.highlightedFile2Content = this.getHighlights(this.file2Content, differences);
      } 
    }
  }

function to get the highlights:

  getHighlights(jsonObject: any, differences: deepDiff.Diff<any, any>[]): string {
    try {
      let jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject, null, 2);
      const lines = jsonString.split('\n');
  
      differences.forEach(diff => {
        if (diff.path && diff.path.length > 0) {
          let valueToHighlight: string | undefined;
          let pathString: string = '';
          let indicesString: string = '';
  
          const indices = diff.path.filter(segment => typeof segment === 'number');
          indicesString = indices.join(', ');
  
          pathString = diff.path.map(segment =>
            typeof segment === 'number' ? `[${segment}]` : `.${segment}`
          ).join('');
  
          switch (diff.kind) {
            case 'E':
              valueToHighlight = JSON.stringify(diff.rhs);
              break;
            case 'N':
              valueToHighlight = JSON.stringify(diff.rhs);
              break;
            case 'D':
              valueToHighlight = JSON.stringify(diff.lhs);
              break;
            case 'A':
              break;
          }
  
          if (valueToHighlight) {
            const regexPath = new RegExp(`("${diff.path[diff.path.length - 1]}":\\s*(${valueToHighlight}))`);
  
            for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
              const match = lines[i].match(regexPath);
              if (match) {
                const matchedValue = match[2];
                lines[i] = lines[i].replace(matchedValue, `<span class="highlight">${matchedValue} DIFFERENCE FOUND! Indices: ${indicesString}</span>`);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
  
      return lines.join('\n');
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error in formatContent:", e);
      return JSON.stringify(jsonObject, null, 2);
    }
  }

I tried to functuon above

You can use a external library to do this ngx-diff instead of writing the function fully.
ngx-diff Demo
ngx-diff Source Code In Demo
